# Resizing and cropping images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using [blueimp's jQuery File Uploader](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) and I'm trying to resize and crop images such that they end up being 75x75 pixels.

How would I do this such that if the user uploads an image (no matter its dimensions) it first resizes it so that its width and height are both at least 75 pixels and then crops the image by the center so that the image ends up being 75x75 pixels?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<img src="imagelinkhere.png" />
<input id="profile-upload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="file-upload/server/php/">
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#profile-upload').fileupload({
        add: function(e, data) {
            var uploadErrors = [];
            var acceptFileTypes = /(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png)$/i;
            if(!acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
                uploadErrors.push('Invalid type.');
            }
            if(data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > 1000000) {
                uploadErrors.push('Image too big.');
            }
            if(uploadErrors.length > 0) {
                alert(uploadErrors);
            } else {
                data.submit();
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that uses a canvas to resize an image. The first argument should be an `Image` object.

```
function(image, width, height) {
    var c = window.document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    c.width = width;
    c.height = height;

    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
    return c.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
}
```

Comment: is this supported in all browsers?IE 7,8,9